# Not able to build ionic3 ipa in mac os 10.13.2 using xcode 9.0

Tags: ios, ionic3

I am trying to build ipa for ionic 3 app in mac using xcode version 9.0.

As per the document I think I got the steps correctly, however I am not able to go through this step.

The error message reads like this:

clang: error: **linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

How can I fix this issue.

Comment: Can you link the document you used to compile it? Can you specify which step you are talking about that is failing? (Give us more information, so we can help you better)

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/   this is the link I followed. I am trying to generate ipa using apple id . When am trying to  build the project with generic ios device am facing this error